Adding CategoryEncoding to the layer causes mismatch in shape
I'm trying to create a Tensorflow model, where I have numerical and categorical features, and this is how I'm adding layers to the model.

num_total_pcats = 26
num_total_ptypes =  7004
num_total_price_band = 5

class TIGMMOE(tfrs.Model):
    def __init__(self, use_cross_layer, deep_layer_sizes, num_units, num_shared_experts, projection_dim=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding_dimension = 8

        self._embeddings = {}
    
        #categorical embedding (common to all tasks)
        self._embeddings['category'] = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_total_pcats + 1, 32)
          ],name='cat_emb')
    
        self._embeddings['ptype'] = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_total_ptypes + 1, 128)
          ],name='ptype_emb')
        
        self._embeddings['anc_price_band'] = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=num_total_price_band, output_mode="multi_hot")
          ],name='anc_price_band_emb')

.
.
.
 def call(self, feat_inputs):
        features = feat_inputs
        anchor_embeddings = []
        
        for feat_name in _CONTEXT_FEATURE_KEYS:
            anchor_embeddings.append(features[feat_name])
        
        anchor_embeddings.append(self._embeddings['category'](features['anc_pcat_map']))
        anchor_embeddings.append(self._embeddings['ptype'](features['anc_ptcode_map']))
        anchor_embeddings.append(self._embeddings['anc_price_band'](features['anc_price_band']))
        
        anchor_embeddings = {}
        anchor_embeddings['anc_feat_vec'] = features['anc_feat_vec']
        anchor_embeddings['anc_ptcode_map_emb'] = self._embeddings['category'](features['anc_pcat_map'])
        anchor_embeddings['anc_pcat_map_emb'] = self._embeddings['ptype'](features['anc_ptcode_map'])
        anchor_embeddings['anc_price_band_emb'] = self._embeddings['anc_price_band'](features['anc_price_band'])
        anchor_embeddings['anc_price_band_emb'] = tf.expand_dims(anchor_embeddings['anc_price_band_emb'], axis=-1)

.
.
.
 x_a = tf.concat([dense_features_rec, 
                            anchor_embeddings['anc_feat_vec'], anchor_embeddings['anc_pcat_map_emb'],
                            anchor_embeddings['anc_ptcode_map_emb'], anchor_embeddings['anc_price_band_emb']], axis=1)

def datasets(file_pattern, batch_size, list_size, mask_feature_name, num_epochs, is_train):
    """Creates the datasets."""
    # Create feature specification.
    context_feature_spec = {}
    context_feature_spec['anc_feat_vec'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(20,), dtype=tf.float32)
    # context_feature_spec['cust_feat_vec'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(29,), dtype=tf.float32)
    context_feature_spec['anc_pcat_map'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0)
    context_feature_spec['anc_ptcode_map'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0)
    context_feature_spec['anc_price_band'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0)

.
.
.

model_data_parameters = {
    'train_files': 'file/.*tfrecords',
    'train_batch_size': 512,
    'valid_batch_size': 512,
    'num_epochs':5,
    '_MASK' : 'rmask',
    'list_size' : 20,
}

train_dataset = datasets(model_data_parameters['train_files'], 
                        128, 
                        model_data_parameters['list_size'], 
                        model_data_parameters['_MASK'], 
                        1, True)

mtl=TIGMMOE(use_cross_layer=True, deep_layer_sizes=[128, 64, 32], num_units=8, num_shared_experts=5, projection_dim=10)

ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(0), optimizer=optimizer, model=mtl)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, './base_mmoe/tf_tr_ckpts', max_to_keep=2)

num_epochs=10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    ft.write(str(epoch))
    ft.write('\n')
    for step, inp_feats in enumerate(train_dataset):
        loss_comb,mets = train_step(inp_feats)
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print('Epoch:', epoch, 'Step:', step , 'loss', loss_comb)
            print(mets)
            auc = mets['auc_b'].numpy()
            if auc>0.6 :
                    save_path = manager.save()
                    print("Saved checkpoint for step {}: {}".format(int(ckpt.step), save_path))
                    ckpt.step.assign_add(1)
            print(mets, file=ft)
            ft.write('\n')
    la,lb,lc = mtl.compute_loss(rr, training=False)


Now I'm getting mismatch in shape because of anc_price_band which is categorical layer.
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/var/tmp/ipykernel_3205159/2753378668.py", line 12, in train_step  *
        loss_a,loss_b,loss_c=mtl.compute_loss(input_features,training=True)
    File "/var/tmp/ipykernel_3205159/4218585440.py", line 499, in compute_loss  *
        logits_a,logits_b,logits_c = self(features, training=training)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/var/tmp/__autograph_generated_file_cif955h.py", line 62, in tf__call
        ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (0, ag__.ld(list_length)), None, fscope), None, loop_body_1, get_state_1, set_state_1, (), {'iterate_names': 'i'})
    File "/var/tmp/__autograph_generated_file_cif955h.py", line 50, in loop_body_1
        x_a = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).concat, ([ag__.ld(dense_features_rec), ag__.ld(anchor_embeddings)['anc_feat_vec'], ag__.ld(anchor_embeddings)['anc_pcat_map_emb'], ag__.ld(anchor_embeddings)['anc_ptcode_map_emb'], ag__.ld(anchor_embeddings)['anc_price_band_emb']],), dict(axis=1), fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'tigmmoe_4' (type TIGMMOE).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/var/tmp/ipykernel_3205159/4218585440.py", line 354, in call  *
            x_a = tf.concat([dense_features_rec,
    
        ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and 5. Shapes are [128] and [5]. for '{{node tigmmoe_4/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=5, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](tigmmoe_4/GatherV2, input_features_1, tigmmoe_4/ptype_emb/embedding_9/embedding_lookup_1/Identity_1, tigmmoe_4/cat_emb/embedding_8/embedding_lookup_1/Identity_1, tigmmoe_4/ExpandDims, tigmmoe_4/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [128,19], [128,20], [128,128], [128,32], [5,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[5] = <1>.
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'tigmmoe_4' (type TIGMMOE):
      • feat_inputs={'rec_feat_vec': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128, 20, 19), dtype=float32)', 'anc_feat_vec': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128, 20), dtype=float32)', 'anc_pcat_map': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128,), dtype=int64)', 'anc_price_band': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128,), dtype=int64)', 'anc_ptcode_map': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128,), dtype=int64)', 'rmask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(128, 20), dtype=bool)'}

Can someone tell me how can I add the layer to match the shape for that layer. anc_price_band is int column with 5 different layers?
